# If n is a natural number, how can I show that the following expression is also a natural number?

Tags: binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

If n is a natural number, show that the following expression is also a natural number

$$\frac{(1+\sqrt 5)^n-(1-\sqrt 5)^n}{2^n\sqrt 5}$$
(I tried to write $a+\sqrt 5b=(1+\sqrt 5)^n$, a and b are integers,then the expression is equal to $\frac{b}{2^{n-1}}$. But I don't know how to go on... Hoping someone could see this

n=1:  $b=1\quad$   $2^{n-1}=1\quad$ quotient=1

n=2:  $b=2\quad$   $2^{n-1}=2\quad$ quotient=1

n=3:  $b=8\quad$    $2^{n-1}=4\quad$ quotient=2

n=4:  $b=24\quad$   $2^{n-1}=8\quad$ quotient=3

Thus I guess $b=(n-1)2^{n-1}$ for $n>1$, but I'm at a loss how to prove it

Comment: Have you worked out the first few terms?  The sequence should be familiar.

Comment: You should edit the question and add your attempts.

Comment: Thanks, I did as you said. I have seen some advancement.

Comment: Hint: think Fibonacci.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Consider the quadratic equation $$x^2-x-1=0$$
If it has roots $\alpha, \beta$, it can be shown quite easily using induction that $$\alpha ^n=F_{n+1}\alpha+F_n$$ where $F_n$ is the $n^{th}$ term of the Fibonacci sequence, viz., $0,1,1,2,3,5,...$.
The same can also be said for powers of $\beta$. Can you now proceed?

Comment: Thank you very much! With your help, I could figure it out now. I just realize it's such an interesting problem!

Comment: By the way, could you please tell me how to make this question to be open again?

Comment: It is indeed an interesting problem. Usually questions here are downvoted and closed if OP doesn't post the context in which the question was faced, and does not attach his/her own work. You did post your own attempt later on, so perhaps the mods would take notice and open it soon.

Comment: I understand now. Thanks a lot!